# Регулярное выражение для выражения в скобках "верхнего уровня"

Tags: python, re

Я пытаюсь составить регулярное выражение, которое правильно найдёт все выражения в фигурных скобках, но проигнорирует все вложенные вхождения. Я не хочу, чтобы регулярное выражение приводило к катастрофическому возврату.
Вот две строки (добавил переносы строк для читаемости):

```
1) "Пакет {0} требует наличия не менее {features.count} функций компании
 {company.name} в городе {company.location.city}"

2) "associated_data = {"package":42, "features":{"count":12, "items":[...]}, 
"company": "name":"Contoso", "location":{"city":"Saint Petersburg"}}}"
```

В первой строке, я хочу матчить:

```
['{0}', '{features.count}', '{company.name}', '{company.location.city}']
```

А во второй строке я хочу матчить:

```
['{"package":42, "features":{"count":12, "items":[...]}, 
"company": "name":"Contoso", "location":{"city":"Saint Petersburg"}}}']
```

Жадный алгоритм, например `r'(?<!\\)\{.*(?<!\\)\}'` валится на первой строке, потому что он матчит целиком:

```
['{0} требует наличия не менее {features.count} функций компании {company.name} 
в городе {company.location.city}']
```

А нежадный (`r'(?<!\\)\{[^{}]*(?<!\\)}'`) валится на втором, потому что берёт:

```
['{"count":12, "items":[...]}', '{"city":"Saint Petersburg"}']
```

Вы спросите - "Как же реджекс должен догадаться что именно ты хочешь?";
Я отвечу - "Регулярное выражение должно находить Наименьшее выражение, обрамлённое правильной парой фигурных скобок на самом Верхнем уровне вложенности.".

Comment: Модуль ```re``` не поддерживает ```'(?R)'```

Comment: Это невозможно в общем случае. Посмотрите тут идеи https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ihDXDz/1 Полагаю, Вы что-то подобное имели ввиду?

Comment: @Namerek Это выглядит как рабочий код, но на самом деле - это не совсем так. Ваш пример зависит от наличия/отсутствия кавычек в фигурных скобках, и это не должно работать так. Содержимое правильных фигурных скобок не важно и на его проверку нельзя полагаться. Ваш regex провалит такой тест ```that not match {{}123} {{}} -> ['{{}123}', '{{}}']```. Важно лишь взаимное расположение фигурных скобок на верхнем уровне, а не то, что внутри. ```(?<!\\)``` я использовал, чтобы игнорировать экранированные фигурные скобки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ок, это **невозможно**.
Вероятно, тогда я остановлюсь на этом варианте:

```
from queue import Queue

def find_all_top_level_expressions(raw_str):
    expression = Queue()
    level = 0
    for character in raw_str:
        if character == '{':
            level += 1
            if level > 0:
                expression.put(character)
        elif character == '}':
            if level > 0:
                expression.put(character)
            level -= 1
            if level == 0 and not expression.empty():
                yield ''.join([expression.get() for _ in range(expression.qsize())])
        elif level > 0:
            expression.put(character)

str1 = 'Пакет {0} требует наличия не менее {features.count} функций компании {company.name} в городе {company.location.city}'
str2 = 'associated_data = {"package":42, "features":{"count":12, "items":[...]}, "company": "name":"Contoso", "location":{"city":"Saint Petersburg"}}}'

for expr in find_add_top_level_expressions(str1):
    print(expr)
```

Comment: Меня беспокоит только вот эта строка с точки зрения производительности: ```yield ''.join([expression.get() for _ in range(expression.qsize())])```

Answer (score 0):

Моё нерекурсивное решение до 4 уровней вложенности:

```
r"\{(?:
    [^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?|
    [^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?|
    [^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?|
    [^{}\r\n]*?(?:\}|\{)[^{}\r\n]*?|
    [^{}\r\n]*?
)\}"gxm
```

[Визуализация регулярки](https://regexper.com/#%5C%7B%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%7C%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%7C%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%7C%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%28%3F%3A%5C%7D%7C%5C%7B%29%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%7C%5B%5E%7B%7D%5Cr%5Cn%5D*%3F%29%5C%7D)

Comment: Жаль, но вот это ```\{(?:([^{}\r\n]*(?:\}|\{))*[^{}\r\n]*|[^{}\r\n]*)\}``` - **не** сработало